# Updating Large SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, list

I am accessing large (10,000+ line item) SharePoint lists from a Power Apps user interface.

I created the lists by exporting them from Excel. The list data is created in another system and the Excel spreadsheet is emailed to me at various times (no there is currently no API connections, discussions are ongoing).

If such functionality exists, what is the most efficient way to update each SharePoint list with fresh data when new Excel spreadsheets are sent to me?

Comment: Are you replacing the existing lists in SharePoint with the new Excel Data? In that case, I would first import the data into a SQL Server Database table (if you have access to SQL server), make the changes using SQL queries, and then export the data to Excel. Then import those excel into SharePoint

Comment: No SQL access. I have SharePoint and Excel Online as data sources.

Comment: Will the new spreadsheet contain brand new data that is added to the list as new items or does it contain changes that need to be applied to the data that already exists in the list from the first spreadsheet?

Comment: More times than not new line items are added or removed from the Excel spreadsheet in every version. The Excel spreadsheets are distributed every 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported to update SharePoint lists from Excel data refresh. Once a list is created by using Export Table to SharePoint List, the list data will be Read-Only from Excel side (if you are not using programmatic methods).

If you are open for Power Automate, you can build a flow to update list data from Excel.
Once the new spreadsheets arrive, you can update the source Excel spreadsheet so that the change will be applied to SharePoint as well.

See a reference here: [Update Sharepoint List From Excel File.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-Sharepoint-List-From-Excel-File/td-p/111477)

Comment: Yes, I performed a similar action using a different flow template I found. I created a flow that reads the SP list, and then read the Excel document. Where there are differences in the Excel document (new items, items changed, or items removed) the flow makes the same changes to the SP list. The flow is set to run every 7 days; which is the frequency at which new Excel spreadsheets are generated. I merely have to copy over the existing Excel spreadsheet once a week, prior to the flow initiating.

Comment: @Curtis Yes, that would be solution in this situation.